# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

Hi I'm currently trying to output information from a database into a table. It was working perfectly until I tried adding a field that includes a Date of Birth and a time. I don't know what to put in the IEnumerable. I have all my other ones as string but was unsure for what to put for this one. Any suggestions? (The error is coming from the last line EmployeeBirthDate.

```
namespace NorthwindWeb.Pages
{
public class EmployeesModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> EmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> EmployeeTitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> EmployeeTitleOfCourtesy{ get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> EmployeeBirthDate{ get; set; }

    private Northwind db;

    public EmployeesModel(Northwind injectedContext)
    {
        db = injectedContext;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Northwind Web Site - Employees";

        EmployeeID = db.Employees.Select(s => s.EmployeeID).OrderBy(EmployeeID => EmployeeID).ToArray();
        EmployeeLastName = db.Employees.Select(s => s.LastName).ToArray();
        EmployeeFirstName = db.Employees.Select(s => s.FirstName).ToArray();
        EmployeeTitle = db.Employees.Select(s => s.Title).ToArray();
        EmployeeTitleOfCourtesy = db.Employees.Select(s => s.TitleOfCourtesy).ToArray();
        EmployeeBirthDate = db.Employees.Select(s => s.BirthDate).ToArray();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a weird way of doing things, but I'm guessing you BirthDate is a `DateTime`. Try `IEnumerable<DateTime>`

Comment: Consider creating a type (a class) that has properties that correspond to a single instance of a single property. For example `public int EmployeeId { get; set; }`. Then populate a collection of instances of that type

Comment: Hi Nathan, Welcome. I am an old programmer, my advice would be to try to get rid of the IEnumerable<> on the fields you are defining. Actually,  I often personally prefer to use plain types as fields rather than get/set properties too, and I would recommend a non-properties simple-field type to people newer to programming. (But some would disagree with me)  So, if you followed me, you might end up with 'public DateTime EmployeeBirthDate;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change

```
public IEnumerable<string> EmployeeBirthDate{ get; set; }
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> EmployeeBirthDate{ get; set; }
```

or change

```
EmployeeBirthDate = db.Employees.Select(s => s.BirthDate).ToArray();
```

to

```
EmployeeBirthDate = db.Employees.Select(s => s.BirthDate.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly and is now displaying correctly. Thanks a lot folks